# HP Pavillion 6 notebook series boot menu option is not working

Tags: windows-8, boot, ubuntu-12.04

I am not getting boot option even after pressing esc key repeatedly during start up. I start my notebook starting pressing esc key to get boot option but instead it boot from hard drive and windows 8 is getting loaded.

Please help me in getting boot option as I want to format windows 8 and install Ubuntu 12.04 using usb drive.

I have already made my usb stick bootable.

Regards,
Pise

Comment: followed this step to get boot screen, after a long search. "go to windows 8 charm bar >settings> change pc settings > general > advande start up click restart now >troubleshoot >advance options> Startup settings>>Restart then press F10 will get boot option".

Comment: was your issue solved? You should have posted that as an answer rather than a comment to the original if so..

Comment: @Loper324 I was trying to post the answer but it was not allowing me to post. There was some validation that question can be answered after certain hours. So now I am posting the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

followed this step to get boot screen, after a long search. "go to windows 8 charm bar >settings> change pc settings > general > advande start up click restart now >troubleshoot >advance options> Startup settings>>Restart then press F10 will get boot option"

Answer (score 0):

It should be f10. If not f2 and f12 are sometimes the lucky numbers as well